# Error when using Java Class in Python with Jpype

Tags: java, python, python-import, jpype

I am trying to use a Java Class from the [*webgraph*](http://webgraph.di.unimi.it) library in a python script, using jpype. I am able to import the class but I can't instantiate it. This is my code:

```
...
####

import jpype
from jpype import *
import os

path_to_jar = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "webgraph")
classpath = ':'.join(
    [os.path.join(path_to_jar, name) for name in os.listdir(path_to_jar)])
jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(), "-ea",
               "-Djava.class.path={}".format(classpath))
ImmutableGraph = JClass('it.unimi.dsi.webgraph.ImmutableGraph')
im = ImmutableGraph.load("graphs/cnr-2000")
...
```

I get the following error:

```
<class 'jpype._jclass.it.unimi.dsi.webgraph.ImmutableGraph$$Static'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "breadth_first_raw.py", line 34, in <module>
    im = ImmutableGraph.load("graphs/cnr-2000")
RuntimeError: No matching overloads found for load in find. at native/common/jp_method.cpp:127
```

Looking at the source code in [*webgraph*](http://webgraph.di.unimi.it), it seems the constructor is expecting a *CharSequence*. The method *load* can be seen on line 524 in [this file](https://github.com/lhelwerd/WebGraph/blob/master/src/it/unimi/dsi/webgraph/ImmutableGraph.java)

```
/** Creates a new {@link ImmutableGraph} by loading a graph file from disk to memory, with 
 *  all offsets, using no progress logger.
 * 
 * <P>This method uses the properties convention described in the {@linkplain ImmutableGraph introduction}.
 *
 * @param basename the basename of the graph.
 * @return an {@link ImmutableGraph} containing the specified graph.
 * @throws IOException if an I/O exception occurs while reading the graph.
 */


public static ImmutableGraph load( CharSequence basename ) throws IOException {
    return load( LoadMethod.STANDARD, basename, null );
}
```

I don't know exactly what is causing the error. I thought the argument of the *load* function could be in the wrong format, thus I tried to use `JString("graphs/cnr-2000")` but it didn't work neither. Is it possible there's something wrong with the path I'm using? 
My directory tree is the following

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── my_script.py
├── graphs
│   ├── cnr-2000.graph
│   ├── cnr-2000.md5sums
│   ├── cnr-2000.obl
│   ├── cnr-2000.offsets
│   └── cnr-2000.properties
└── webgraph
    ├── all_jars* 
    ..
```